# Python add / to output string

Tags: python, string, formatting

i
I am trying to pass some values via udp and I need to send /v in the output however is keeps being sent in UT8.

code as below;

Print to terminal outputs correctly showing \ v
however when i read the data coming into the udp session it is displayed as \x5C

```
print thermostat,'\x5c',"v =",roomtemp
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                socket.SOCK_DGRAM) #UDP
     sock.sendto(str(thermostat)+'\x5c'+'v = '+str(roomtemp), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

Comment: So, you have to send `\v` not `/v`?

Comment: `\x5c` is actually `'\'`. If you assign `\x5c` to a variable, and ask for this variable, python will give you `\x5c`. However, if you print that out, python will print `'\'`.

Comment: Yes I want to send \v its just what the loxone uses to interpret a value change. How can I get python to us '\' in the final string rather than the character value??